Problem when trying to generate PDF files within Django with libreoffice
I have a Django application based on the 3.10.11-alpine3.16 image that runs in a docker container.  When I check during the build if a sample PDF is generated, this will succeed, and I see that when running with root it is okay. The problem is that when I try to issue the same command in the running container's terminal, I get an error and I don't know why.
In my dockerfile I have the commands to install the libreoffice:
RUN apk add --no-cache 
xmlsec xmlsec-dev 
libreoffice 
libreoffice-writer 
libreoffice-calc 
libreoffice-impress 
libreoffice-base 
ttf-dejavu 
unzip 
wget 
curl 
openjdk11-jre
This commands runs perfectly during build in the name of the root user:
RUN soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir /vol/logs /vol/logs/word_sample_01.docx
If I try to run the same command when I logged into the docker's terminal, so for example:
/usr/bin/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir /vol/logs/t/ /vol/logs/word_sample_01.docx
I get this error: "Unspecified Application Error"
I assume it is related to some permissions, but I can't figure out which one is missing...
15 of June - some further information: I switched now to another version of alpine image (to python:3.12.4-alpine3.20). With this image the LibreOffice 7.6.7.2 60(Build:2) will be automatically installed.  I created the HOME/.config directory (mkdir /home/django-user/.config) and I granted full privileges to the user.
In addition to this I added the user to the SUDO group in order to make it able to execute any command:
RUN echo "django-user ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
RUN echo "%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
Despite all my efforts, the situation is unchanged: the root can execute the command, the django-user gets the following error:
command: convert /vol/logs/testfile2.txt as a Writer document -> /vol/logs/testfile2.pdf using filter : writer_pdf_Export
convert /vol/logs/testfile2.txt as a Writer document -> /vol/logs/testfile2.pdf using filter : writer_pdf_Export
Error: Please verify input parameters... (SfxBaseModel::impl_store file:///vol/logs/testfile2.pdf failed: 0xc10(Error Area:Io Class:Write Code:16) at /home/buildozer/aports/community/libreoffice/src/libreoffice-7.6.7.2/sfx2/source/doc/sfxbasemodel.cxx:3221 at /home/buildozer/aports/community/libreoffice/src/libreoffice-7.6.7.2/sfx2/source/doc/sfxbasemodel.cxx:1792)
I checked out the link suggested below by nigel (github.com/sgbj/versed) but as far as I see that solution operates with root privileges.
Any hints?

You may have gotten further than I did! I gave up on alpine and based on ubuntu 24.04. A recent question I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78617606/what-is-ubuntu-recommending-that-fixes-libreoffice-convert-to-pdf-problem?noredirect=1#comment138604550_78617606 gives some details.

Something I found for myself is a converter service https://github.com/sgbj/versed, based on Libreoffice. You might find it or its source useful. It's based on alpine.

Hi, some further information:

the only thing I can think of is make sure the user can write to /vol/logs/testfile2.pdf (from the error,  file:///vol/logs/testfile2.pdf failed ...). You might log this as an issue with the LIbreoffice team, you can offer them a Docker image which precisely exhibits the error.
